# canvas to svg translate with animation

Tags: javascript, svg, html5-canvas

I have been using a [JavaScript library](https://github.com/darkskyapp/skycons) to make animated weather symbols. I am doing now a SVG version  of [the cloud symbol](http://jsfiddle.net/wyj51v2b/), and wonder which approach might be best.

So I made a trace/path of the cloud, static ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bmsvypb9/)) and [basic rotation isn't the right effect](http://jsfiddle.net/bmsvypb9/2/) since the original cloud ([in the js canvas animation](http://jsfiddle.net/wyj51v2b/)) has 5 curves basically and they expand and contract while they turn.

Possible approaches I think of:

- making 5 circles, using dash to just show the arc wanted and then animating & expanding/contracting the circles
- making 5 [sub-paths](http://jsfiddle.net/bmsvypb9/1/) and somehow animate expansion and contracting them
- using 5 animateMotion animation

Is there a better logic for this? any pointers on how to think this logic would be great.

The same example as jsFiddle above, using the SE app:

```js
var skycons = new Skycons({
    "color": "black"
});
var canvas = document.querySelectorAll('canvas');
[].forEach.call(canvas, function (el) {
    skycons.add(el, el.dataset.icon);
});

skycons.play();
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/darkskyapp/skycons/master/skycons.js"></script>
<div class="fe_forecast">
    <div class="fe_currently">
        <canvas id="fe_current_icon" data-icon="cloudy" width="160" height="160" style="width:120px; height:120px"></canvas>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't think `<animateMotion>` can help for this, what is animated here is your points. You could try with `<animate  attributeName="points">` and setting the `from` to your starting `d` path and the `to` to the last one you got from your canvas code. Or, since svg's and canvas' path drawing commands are quite similar, you should be able to tweak the code for it to animate your svg path.

Comment: @Kaiido StueyTheScout tried that suggestion. Was that what you had in mind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got misled by the svg code you provided :

I first thought that your canvas code was drawing a Path2d, with `moveTo`, `arcTo` or `quadraticCurveTo` methods which would have been quite easy to tweak in order to interact with your svg's path `d` attribute, since canvas's path commands are almost the same as SVG's ones.

But, I guess you got the current svg code by converting the bitmap into vectors through a soft like InkScape or Illustrator.

Actually, what the Skycons code does is that it draws 5 circles, while preforming a compositeOperation so only the non-overlapping strokes are visible.

Here I modified the code so it becomes obvious :

```js
(function(global) {
  "use strict";

      var requestInterval = function(fn, delay) {
        var handle = {value: null};
        function loop() {
          handle.value = requestAnimationFrame(loop);
          fn();
        }
        loop();
        return handle;
      },
      cancelInterval = function(handle) {
        cancelAnimationFrame(handle.value);
      };

  var KEYFRAME = 500,
      STROKE = 0.08,
      TAU = 2.0 * Math.PI,
      TWO_OVER_SQRT_2 = 2.0 / Math.sqrt(2);

  function circle(ctx, x, y, r) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x, y, r, 0, TAU, false);
    ctx.stroke();
  }

  function puff(ctx, t, cx, cy, rx, ry, rmin, rmax) {
    var c = Math.cos(t * TAU),
        s = Math.sin(t * TAU);

    rmax -= rmin;

    circle(
      ctx,
      cx - s * rx,
      cy + c * ry + rmax * 0.5,
      rmin + (1 - c * 0.5) * rmax
    );
  }

  function puffs(ctx, t, cx, cy, rx, ry, rmin, rmax) {
    var i;
    for(i = 5; i--; )
      puff(ctx, t + i / 5, cx, cy, rx, ry, rmin, rmax);
  }

  function cloud(ctx, t, cx, cy, cw, s, color) {
    t /= 30000;

    var a = cw * 0.21,
        b = cw * 0.12,
        c = cw * 0.24,
        d = cw * 0.28;

    puffs(ctx, t, cx, cy, a, b, c, d);
    puffs(ctx, t, cx, cy, a, b, c - s, d - s);

  }

  var Skycons = function(opts) {
        this.list        = [];
        this.interval    = null;
        this.color       = opts && opts.color ? opts.color : "black";
        this.resizeClear = !!(opts && opts.resizeClear);
      };

  Skycons.CLOUDY = function(ctx, t, color) {
    var w = ctx.canvas.width,
        h = ctx.canvas.height,
        s = Math.min(w, h);
    cloud(ctx, t, w * 0.5, h * 0.5, s, s * STROKE, color);
  };


  Skycons.prototype = {
    _determineDrawingFunction: function(draw) {
      if(typeof draw === "string")
        draw = Skycons[draw.toUpperCase().replace(/-/g, "_")] || null;

      return draw;
    },
    add: function(el, draw) {
      var obj;

      if(typeof el === "string")
        el = document.getElementById(el);

      // Does nothing if canvas name doesn't exists
      if(el === null)
        return;

      draw = this._determineDrawingFunction(draw);

      // Does nothing if the draw function isn't actually a function
      if(typeof draw !== "function")
        return;

      obj = {
        element: el,
        context: el.getContext("2d"),
        drawing: draw
      };

      this.list.push(obj);
      this.draw(obj, KEYFRAME);
    },
    set: function(el, draw) {
      var i;

      if(typeof el === "string")
        el = document.getElementById(el);

      for(i = this.list.length; i--; )
        if(this.list[i].element === el) {
          this.list[i].drawing = this._determineDrawingFunction(draw);
          this.draw(this.list[i], KEYFRAME);
          return;
        }

      this.add(el, draw);
    },
    remove: function(el) {
      var i;

      if(typeof el === "string")
        el = document.getElementById(el);

      for(i = this.list.length; i--; )
        if(this.list[i].element === el) {
          this.list.splice(i, 1);
          return;
        }
    },
    draw: function(obj, time) {
      var canvas = obj.context.canvas;

      if(this.resizeClear)
        canvas.width = canvas.width;

      else
        obj.context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

      obj.drawing(obj.context, time, this.color);
    },
    play: function() {
      var self = this;

      this.pause();
      this.interval = requestInterval(function() {
        var now = Date.now(),
            i;

        for(i = self.list.length; i--; )
          self.draw(self.list[i], now);
      }, 1000 / 60);
    },
    pause: function() {
      var i;
      if(this.interval) {
        cancelInterval(this.interval);
        this.interval = null;
      }
    }
  };

  global.Skycons = Skycons;
}(this));
var skycons = new Skycons({
    "color": "black"
});
var canvas = document.querySelectorAll('canvas');
[].forEach.call(canvas, function (el) {
    skycons.add(el, el.dataset.icon);
});

skycons.play();
```

```html
<canvas id="fe_current_icon" data-icon="cloudy" width="160" height="160" style="width:120px; height:120px"></canvas>
```

To reproduce the same animation, you indeed will have to create an `<animationPath>` for your circles, and then set their `keyPoints` and `keyTimes` respectively.
Browsers still doesn't support [svg's compositing operations](http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-SVGCompositing-20090430/), so you will have to use a `<clipPath>`and declare twice your circles animation.

Here is an example :

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="-30 -30 160 160" width=200 height=200>
  <defs>
    <style>
      circle {stroke: #000; stroke-width: 7px; fill: white;}
    </style>

    <path id="mainmotion" d="M15.5-3.9c13.2,0,23.9,7.4,23.9,16.5S28.7,29.2,15.5,29.2S-8.4,21.8-8.4,12.7S2.3-3.9,15.5-3.9"/>
 
 <g id="g">
 <circle id="c1" cx="37.7" cy="32.3" r="27.5">
        <animateMotion dur="6s" repeatCount="indefinite" calcMode="linear" keyPoints="0; 0.2; 0.4; 0.6; 0.8; 1" keyTimes="0; 0.2; 0.4; 0.6; 0.8; 1">
          <mpath xlink:href="#mainmotion" />
        </animateMotion>
      </circle>
      <circle id="c2" cx="37.7" cy="32.3" r="27.5">
        <animateMotion dur="6s" repeatCount="indefinite" calcMode="linear" keyPoints="0.2; 0.4; 0.6; 0.8; 1; 0; 0.2" keyTimes="0; 0.2; 0.4; 0.6; 0.8; 0.8; 1">
          <mpath xlink:href="#mainmotion" />
        </animateMotion>
      </circle>
      <circle id="c3" cx="37.7" cy="32.3" r="27.5">
        <animateMotion dur="6s" repeatCount="indefinite" calcMode="linear" keyPoints="0.4; 0.6; 0.8; 1; 0; 0.2; 0.4" keyTimes="0; 0.2; 0.4; 0.6; 0.6; 0.8; 1">
          <mpath xlink:href="#mainmotion" />
        </animateMotion>
      </circle>
      <circle id="c4" cx="37.7" cy="32.3" r="27.5">
        <animateMotion dur="6s" repeatCount="indefinite" calcMode="linear" keyPoints="0.6; 0.8; 1; 0; 0.2; 0.4; 0.6" keyTimes="0; 0.2; 0.4; 0.4; 0.6; 0.8; 1">
          <mpath xlink:href="#mainmotion" />
        </animateMotion>
      </circle>
      <circle id="c5" cx="37.7" cy="32.3" r="27.5">
        <animateMotion dur="6s" repeatCount="indefinite" calcMode="linear" keyPoints="0.8; 1; 0; 0.2; 0.4; 0.6; 0.8" keyTimes="0; 0.2; 0.2; 0.4; 0.6; 0.8; 1">
          <mpath xlink:href="#mainmotion" />
        </animateMotion>
      </circle>
    </g>
    <clipPath id="clip">
  <use xlink:href="#c1"/>
  <use xlink:href="#c2"/>
  <use xlink:href="#c3"/>
  <use xlink:href="#c4"/>
  <use xlink:href="#c5"/>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
 <use xlink:href="#g"/>
 <rect x=0 y=0 width=160 height=160 clip-path="url(#clip)" fill="white" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Very intersting! Thank you for giving a extra look into this. Will checkout your logic and try to take it further.

Comment: @Sergio, actually I did something stupid in first rev. You can have only one `animationPath` and set each circle's `keyPoints` and `keyTimes` attribute to achieve the same effect...

Comment: Ok, will check. You deom now is statis, but will follow up the idea.

Comment: Yep, Chrome doesn't seem to appreciate the `calcMode='spline'` option... Changed it to linear and it seems to fix the issue

Comment: Thank you again for the feedback. Looks great!